# Jordan Block of Kronecker Product

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensor-products, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $(p\times p$)-Jordan block of generalized eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $B$ be a $(q\times q$)-Jordan block of generalized eigenvalue $\mu$. Then what is the Jordan canonical form for $A\otimes B$, where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product?

I found a reference here without a proof (Horn, Roger A., and Charles R. Johnson. Matrix analysis. Cambridge university press, 1990.):

[image]

[image]

I will be appreciated if anyone can give me a proof of part (a).