# The Jordan Canonical Form of linear operator in two variables polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I've been trying to solve the following exercise,

> In the space of bivariate polynomials of the form $f(x,y)=\sum_{n,m=0}^2a_{n,m}x^ny^m$, the lineal operator $T$ is defined by $Tf(x,y)=f(x+1,y+1)$. Obtain a Jordan Canonical Form of T

I think i've made considerable progress, but I'm concerned i am taking the longest path, and i would like to know if there exist an easy way. Let $V$ be the space of bivariate polynomials of degree at most 4, I've done the following,

> First, I expressed the operator as
> $$Tf(x,y)=\sum_{m=0}^2(y+1)^m\left[(a_{0,m}+a_{1,m}+a_{2,m})+ x(a_{1,m}+2a_{2,m})+x^2a_{2,m}\right]$$
> Then I observed that whenever $T$ is applied to a function $f$ in $V$, then the non-zero coefficients of the same degree as the polynomial (non-zero coefficients with maximum $n+m$) remain the same. This implies that the only possible eigenvalue is $\lambda=1$.
> To find the eigenvector i tried to found the set of functions $f\in V$ such that $Tf-\lambda f=Tf-f=0$, using the expressions above it's possible to write the following
> $$\array{
> f(x+1,y+1)-f(x,y)=&\sum_{m=0}^2[(y+1)^m(a_{0,m}+a_{1,m}+a_{2,m})-y^ma_{0,m}]+\\ 
> &x\sum_{m=0}^2[(y+1)^m(a_{1,m}+2a_{2,m})-y^ma_{1,m}]+\\
> &x^2\sum_{m=0}^2[(y+1)^ma_{2,m}-y^ma_{2,m}]
> }
> $$
> Then if this polynomial is $0$ everywhere then if we treat $y$ as a constant the univariate polynomial is $0$ everywhere and then each coeficient is $0$, i.e every sum in the expression above is $0$ and because this is true for every $y$ then this is also a $0$ everywhere polynomial for $y$ where every coefficient should be $0$, after doing this I got a equation system that has a solution only when the following is true
> $$ 
>      \begin{cases}
>        a_{2,2}=a_{2,1}=a_{1,2}=0\\
>        a_{1,1}+2a_{2_0}=0 \\
>        a_{0,1}+a_{1,0}=0\\
>        a_{0,2}=a_{0,2}\\ 
>      \end{cases}$$
> We can refer to $f\in V$ by it's coefficents, this means $f$ can be expressed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^9$, in the cannonical basis $f$ can be represented as $f=(a_{0,0},a_{0,1},a_{1,0},a_{0,2},a_{2,0},a_{1,1},a_{2,1},a_{1,2},a_{2,2})$, then a base of the eigenspace  can be given by
> $$\array{
> v_1=(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\\
> v_2=(0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)\\
> v_3=(0,0,0,1,1,-2,0,0,0)\\
> }$$

I consider that analyzing the powers of $(T-\lambda I)$, like $(T-\lambda I)^2$ or $(T-\lambda I)^3$ is going to be a struggle, so, how should I construct the Jordan canonical form here?

Comment: one may write the matrix for $T$ in your chosen basis, it will be a 9 by 9 matrix. I admit, not elegant. Maybe start by doing just (individual) degrees up to 1,  basis $1,x,y,xy$ and a 4 by 4 matrix

Comment: beginning the easier problem $a + bx + cy + dxy$  becomes $ a + b(x+1) + c (y+1) + d (x+1)(y+1) $  I get $(a+b+c+d) + (b+d)x + (c+d)y + dxy$  All eigenvalues 1, minimal polynomial $(x-1)^3$  so there is a 3 by 3 Jordan block and a loner.

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete solution, but I do think that things are greatly simplified (esp. when we pass to polynomials of degree $n$) by using the basis ${x+k \choose k}$ instead of the basis $x^k$, and ditto for the $y$s. The matrix of $T_1$ ($x\mapsto x+1$ on space of $x$s) is then upper-triangular with all entries above the diagonal equal to $1$. It's probably easier to look at $T_{1}^{-1}$, which is a single Jordan block. The result referenced by @Jean Marie tells us what the answer is, and in small cases it is easy to check this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix of your operator is in fact a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), bringing an important conceptual and technical simplification.

Let me take the simplified case considered by Will Jagy where operator $P(x,y) \to P(x+1,y+1)$ is restricted to the space $\mathbb{R}_{1,1}[x,y]$ with **bi**variate polynomials with degree at most 1 in x and at most one in y. Its matrix with respect to base $(1,x,y,xy)$ is:

$$T_{1,1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&1&1&1\\0&1&0&1\\ \hline0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right)$$

can be partitionned in order to recognize in it the  Kronecker product of a certain matrix with itself:

$$T_{1,1}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\\color{green}{0}&\color{cyan}{1}\end{pmatrix}}_{T_1} \otimes \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{T_1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}\color{red}{1}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}&\color{blue}{1}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\ \color{green}{0}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}&\color{cyan}{1}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{array}\right) $$

The first matrix $T_1$ represents operator $P(x)\to P(x+1)$ in **uni**variate polynomials of degree at most $1$, the second matrix (of course identical) corresponding to the similar operation $Q(y) \to Q(y+1)$ on the other variable.

For your case, you just have to consider the $9 \times 9$ matrix:

$$T_{2,2}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{T_2} \otimes \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{T_2}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&2&0&1&2&0&1&2\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&2&2&2\\
0&0&0&0&1&2&0&2&4\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&2\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&2\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Matrices that can be expressed into the form of Kronecker products have many properties. For example their eigenvalues/vectors are very easy to get using the eigenvalues/vectors of their constituents. Dealing with the Jordan form of a Kronecker product, we have a theorem recalled [here] ([Jordan Block of Kronecker Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718267)) (coming from Horn and Johnson classical book) giving the number of Jordan blocks: we must expect blocks of size

$$5=3+3-1, \ \ 3=3+3-3, \ \ 1=3+3-5$$

which is indeed the case. One can verify that $$V^{-1}T_{2,2}V=J$$

with

$$J=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\end{smallmatrix}\right) \&
V=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}24& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0&12&-12&12&-6& 1& 0&-2&-4\\
0& 0& 2&-5&11& 0&  0.5&-1.25&-2\\
0&12& 0&-4& 0&-1& 0& 2& 4\\
0& 0& 8&-8& 0& 0& 0& 2& 4\\
0& 0& 0& 2&-6& 0& 0& 0.5& 0\\
0& 0& 2& 1& 0& 0&-0.5&-0.75&-2\\
0& 0& 0& 2& 0& 0& 0&-0.5& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Results obtained with the following Matlab program:

```
 T2=[1 1 1;
     0 1 2;
     0 0 1]
 jordan(T2), % gives matrix [1 1 0;0 1 1;0 0 1]
 T22=kron(T2,T2)
 [V,J]=jordan(T22)
 inv(V)*T22*V-J, % gives 0 matrix
```

Another reference for Jordan decomposition of Kronecker products: Theorem 56 p. 48 of this [MSc. thesis](https://digitalcommons.unf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=etd).

Comment: Hi, Jean. For the 9 by 9, I get: all eigenvalues 1, one 5 by 5 Jordan block, one 3 by 3 block, one 1 by 1 block. I made a 9 by 9 matrix for $T$ and played with it, constructed the actual change of basis matrix , large determinant of that doing it my way

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks ! As I wanted to do it "the other way", it will help me to check my results...

Comment: Good, I've never done anything with Kronecker product

Comment: @Will Jagy At the beginning , I was reluctant to work with this technique, a remote cousin of tensor calculus, but, finally I discovered it is extremely effective on some category of problems.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, the 9 by 9 matrix has also some entries that are 2 and one position 4, along with many 1 and many 0;

Comment: @Will Jagy It's what I find as well.

Comment: @Will Jagy I confirm : one 5 by 5 block, one 3 by 3, one 1 by 1, using the theorem mentionned (the dimensions of the blocks are in fact 5=3+3−1,3=3+3−3,1=3+3−5). I can give details of course to you (and to the OP if he manifests his presence...)

Comment: @Will Jagy Here in France, it's past midnight, time to count sheep instead of dimensions of eigenspaces... Good evening!

Comment: Sleep well. I think I have the wrong Horn and Johnson book

Comment: getting there. I think your basis for the 9 by 9 is ordered as: $1,x,x^2, y,xy, x^2 y, y^2, x y^2, x^2 y^2$

Comment: yes, that order does give your matrix. Intriguing

Comment: I have added some "technical" stuff at the end.

Comment: Did you know that the particular ordered basis would produce a matrix that would be a Kronecker product? Oh, it turns out it is  the Horn and Johnson Topics book has this material.

Comment: @Will Jagy No, I would say I "smelled it" as the bases of these kind of spaces $\mathbb{R}_{p,q}[X,Y]$ are obtained by tensorising bases of $\mathbb{R}_{p}[X]$ and $\mathbb{R}_{q}[Y]$ . It is only afterwards that I made a Google search, thinking that maybe the Jordan decomposition may be obtained in a straightforward manner, and found this theorem.  I was not at all aware of its existence.

Comment: That makes sense; so, when we take the Kronecker product of a column vector $v$  and a row vector $w,$   the result is the same matrix as the ordinary matrix multiplication $vw.$  Here I am thinking of  $v=(1,x,x^2)^T$  and $w=(1,y,y^2)$

Answer (score 1):

A more brute-force approach: clearly $1,\,x-y$ and $(x-y)^2$ are eigenvectors of $T$. Therefore we expect the matrix of $T$ to look simpler if the ordered basis contains them as members, with probably some other members divisible by $x-y$. When the characteristic of the underlying field is $0$, we may try the following:
$$
\{1,\,x+y,\,xy,\,(x-y)^2,\,xy(x+y),\,x^2y^2,\,x-y,\,(x+y)(x-y),\,xy(x-y)\}.
$$
The matrix of $T$ with respect to this ordered basis is
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&1&0&2&1\\ &1&1&0&3&2\\ &&1&0&6&6\\ &&&1&1&1\\ &&&&1&2\\ &&&&&1\\ &&&&&&1&2&1\\ &&&&&&&1&1\\ &&&&&&&&1}.
$$
Let $B=A(1:6,1:6)-I_6$. It is straightforward to verify that $\operatorname{rank}(B)=4$ and $B^4\ne0=B^5$. Therefore the Jordan form of $B$ is $J_5(0)\oplus0$. Also, the Jordan form of $A(7:9,7:9)-I_3$ is obviously $J_3(0)$. Hence the Jordan form of $T$ is $J_5(1)\oplus J_3(1)\oplus1$.