# Find a similiar matrix with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

I need to find a $4 \times 4$ unitary matrix $U$ such that for any $$M =\left(\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$$ where $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb C$ are arbitrary,
$$ U(M \otimes M) U^{\dagger}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
* & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & * & * & * \\
0 & * & * & * \\
0 & * & * & *
\end{array}\right)$$
If $M$ were diagonalizable, I could find a $2\times 2$ unitary $U_2$ such that $U_2MU_2^\dagger=D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then, taking $U=U_2\otimes U_2$ would have solved the problem. But in general $M$ is not diagonalizable. Hence I'm still lacking a general solution.

Comment: Is there a reason that you believe that this is generally possible?

Comment: It might help to make use of the result [referenced here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2718267/81360)

Comment: Could you state the problem as it was given in the problem set? For instance, I strongly suspect that it states "show that [such a unitary matrix] exits" rather than "find a unitary matrix [fulfilling the criteria]"

Comment: Now that I've figured it out, that makes sense... it is indeed the case that the same matrix $U$ works for all matrices $M \in \Bbb C^{2 \times 2}$.

Comment: Well the wording of the question, if taken literally, implies that this is what is required. It's the difference between "find a unitary matrix such that for any $M$..." and "for any $M$... find a unitary matrix such that...".

Comment: Aah yes. Now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Solution Outline:** A matrix $U$ satisfies this condition if and only if its first column (which I will call $u$) is such that both $\operatorname{span}(u)$ and $u^\perp$ are $M \otimes M$ invariant subspaces.

Now, note that if $u$ is of the form $x \otimes y - y \otimes x$ for vectors $x,y \in \Bbb C^2$, then $(M\otimes M)u$ is another vector of this form. Thus, $\mathcal U_1 = \operatorname{span}(\{x \otimes y - y\otimes x: x,y \in \Bbb C^2\})$ is an $M \otimes M$ invariant subspace. Show that $\mathcal U_1$ is $1$-dimensional. Similarly, show that its orthogonal complement $\mathcal U_2 = \mathcal U_1^\perp$ is an $M \otimes M$ invariant subspace. In order to show that this is the case, it may help to first show that
$$
\mathcal U_2 = \operatorname{span}(\{x \otimes x: x \in \Bbb C^2\}).
$$
You might find this all more intuitive if you think of vectors of the form $x \otimes y$ as $2 \times 2$ matrices. Note that there is a (unique) linear isomorphism $\phi:\Bbb C^4 \to \Bbb C^{2 \times 2}$ such that $\phi(x \otimes y) = xy^T$. What kind of matrix is $\phi(u)$ for $u \in \mathcal U_1$? What about for $u \in \mathcal U_2$?

**Further Hint:** The first column of $U$ is $u = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,-1,0)$. It makes no difference what the remaining columns are, so long as $U$ has orthonormal columns.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about the fact that $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U_2}$ are respectively one and three dimensional? For the former, $x, y$ are varying among all possibilities? In that case I think it should be the full space and thus have dimension 4

Comment: @Extreme What exactly do you mean by “it” should be the full space? Do you think that both $\mathcal U_1$ and $\mathcal U_2$ are equal to $\Bbb C^4$?

Comment: @Extreme_Math I would recommend that you go through the computation of $x \otimes y - y \otimes x$ for several choices of $x,y$. As my “further hint” suggests, you should end up with a multiple of $(0,1,-1,0)$.

Comment: If I consider all the possible values $ x, y \in \{e_1,e_2\}$ where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the canonical base of $\mathbf{C}^2$, the tensor product $x \times y$ assumes all the values of the vector in a basis of the tensor product $\mathbf{C}^2 \otimes \mathbf{C}^2$, thus if $x,y$ are not fixed a priori $\mathcal{U}_1$ has dimension 4.  I was wondering what I am missing about your argument and if you are fixing $x,y$ before constructing $\mathcal{U}_1$

Comment: @Extreme I had a typo in my definition of $\mathcal U_1$, see my latest edit